# Find an element in an array that matches the regex given

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, date

I am having an array of different elements in the string format, I wanted to check whether an array contains date field in it. Currently I am thinking of using a date regex and then match it with all the elements in an array, but I am not sure of how to use that.

```
 let arr = ['SUPERMARKET', '465', 'S', 'Arroyo', 'Pkwy', 'Pasadena,', 'CA', '91105', '1', '1', '1', 'DOZ', 'FREE', 'RANGE', 'EGG', '$3.89', 'GV', 'ORGANIC', 'MILK', '2%', '$4.19', 'SBUX', 'FRENCH', 'ROAST', 'WL', '$8.99', 'SUBTOTAL', '$17.07', 'TOTAL', '$17.07', '$17.07', 'PURCHASE', '$17.07', 'VISA', 'DEBIT', '3991', 'Auth', '#140987', 'Exp', 'Date', '**/**', 'Lane', '#14', 'Cashier', '1409', '11/21/2019', '01:28', 'PMRef/Seq', '#140987', 'MRCH', '204650', 'Term=001', 'IC=CC', 'EPS', 'Sequence', '934518', 'ITEM', '1', 'H,', 'STEPHIE', '11/21/2019', '01:28', 'PM', '4130', '29', '1041', '2675']

 let dateRegex = "^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$"
```

Comment: Do you want to return the date(s) or just a boolean value?

Comment: In title you say find an element and in description you say that you want to check whether it contains an element it's a little bit misleading.

Comment: See [*MDN: Array.prototype.some*](https://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs2041/doc/MDN_javascript_reference/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some.html). It will return true if any element in the array returns *true* when passed to the callback, so `let containsDate = arr.some(value => dateRegex.test(value))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
let arr = ['SUPERMARKET', '465', 'S', 'Arroyo', 'Pkwy', 'Pasadena,', 'CA', '91105', '1', '1', '1', 'DOZ', 'FREE', 'RANGE', 'EGG', '$3.89', 'GV', 'ORGANIC', 'MILK', '2%', '$4.19', 'SBUX', 'FRENCH', 'ROAST', 'WL', '$8.99', 'SUBTOTAL', '$17.07', 'TOTAL', '$17.07', '$17.07', 'PURCHASE', '$17.07', 'VISA', 'DEBIT', '3991', 'Auth', '#140987', 'Exp', 'Date', '**/**', 'Lane', '#14', 'Cashier', '1409', '11/08/2019', '01:28', 'PMRef/Seq', '#140987', 'MRCH', '204650', 'Term=001', 'IC=CC', 'EPS', 'Sequence', '934518', 'ITEM', '1', 'H,', 'STEPHIE', '11/12/2019', '01:28', 'PM', '4130', '29', '1041', '2675']

let dateRegex = /^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$/

arr.forEach(e => {
  if(dateRegex.test(e)) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

Note:

- The dates in your current data are "11/21/2019" of format `mm/dd/yyyy`, while the regex you use is of the format `dd/mm/yyyy` so the `dd` part in your dates('21') wont match the regex. I have changed the dates in this answer to match the regex.
- OR you can change the regex to match the date(`mm/dd/yyyy`), by using: `^([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$`
- You can use regex as they are if you place them between `/` instead of quotes `"`

Comment: Yes my regex is not working for this date format. MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @zaidmohammad try the regex I added to match dates of format 'mm/dd/yyyy' .

Answer (score -1):

```
arr.filter(x=>x.match(whateEverRegex))
```

this will return every element that satisfies `x.match(whateEverRegex)`

Comment: and rather use [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) than `match` as it returns a boolean

Comment: RegExp.test() returns the element instead of boolean

Comment: @zaidmohammad `RegExp.test()` [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#returns) a boolean. Per the docs: *'Returns `true` if there is a match between the regular expression and the string str. Otherwise, `false`.'*

Comment: *match* returns an array, or null if no match is found. The result will be coerced to boolean true or false by *filter*, so the array itself is redundant. On the other hand, *test* returns a boolean which is used by *filter* with no further processing.